# DRF pagination_class not returning paginating results

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to paginate the results of a ViewSet but can't get the response to paginate the data.

When I set a global pagination it works fine, however I don't want to do this and override all my views/viewsets that come from `GenericAPIView`, because I only want paginate on one class.

```
"""
don't want to do this, but this works showing that my view is based off of `GenericAPIView`.

# settings.py 
"""
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination'
}
```

When I remove the default setting, this view loses the paginated results

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class ClipViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClipSerializer
    queryset = Clip.objects.all()
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
```

From all indications in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#setting-the-pagination-style) this should be completely possible, and I'm not sure why in my project it's not working. I'm using django 1.9.7 and DRF 3.4.0

Comment: Are you using the correct `page_size`? Try setting it to a smaller value in your view and try it.

Comment: yeah currently there are 11 results and i've set `page_size` to 5 and it doesn't paginate (except for when i set default in settings)

Comment: Looks to be a bug to me. You can open an issue in DRF's github repo.

Comment: @SudipKafle I've come to the same conclusion, already posted we'll see what they say https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4304

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug. As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L174), the default page size for `PageNumberPagination` is `None`, that means that the pagination is disabled, even if you explicitly indicated a paginator class.

You need to subclass `PageNumberPagination` with your required `page_size` to be able to activate pagination:

```
class MyPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5

class ClipViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = MyPageNumberPagination
```

Please note you need to set `page_size` *on the paginator class*, not on the view.

Or put the page size in global settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5
}
```

Then you can use directly `PageNumberPagination`.

Comment: I believe it to be a bug, or at the least a documention problem if they don't want you to be able to choose different page sizes on different views. But yeah I came to the same conclusion and it's moved more in the scope of github issues rather than stackoverflow.  For anyone else looking into this - https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4304

Comment: Well you can use different page sizes for different views, you just have to use different subclasses of `PageNumberPagination` with the page sizes you want (as stated in [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#configuration)). But I agree it's not a very intuitive and convenient design IMHO.

Comment: this ended up being an issue with the docs that tom updated this morning in master (never stated that `PAGE_SIZE` setting is required to use `pagination_class` on a view), which is what led me down this route of confusion.